# How to place sprite kit elements overtop of regular UIKit elements

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to geive the user the ability to drag a skspritenode over a UIImageView and UIButton, but whenever I create the scene it appears behind the UI elements. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that is just not possible. All the sprites and any other elements are rendered frame by frame on the SKScene node and cannot be "dragged" or placed anywhere else. These are not UIKit elements.

In this case, your view is acting as the SKScene and hence all the sprites are being rendered onto that.

Answer (score 1):

SKView is a UIView/NSView in itself. All the Sprite Kit nodes (the scene is also a node) are constituents of the SKView and contained within it. You can only change the draw order of views but not their contents.

To give an example: what you're trying to do is the equivalent of trying to place a UIImageView on top of a UIButton's background but below the UIButton's label.

While technically you could achieve this for plain UIView elements with some trickery, the same will never work for Sprite Kit nodes. They aren't views to begin with but drawn onto an OpenGL framebuffer represented/managed by the SKView. From the perspective of Cocoa an SKView is a single view with no subviews in it.

Simply put: nodes are not views, and nodes are technically incompatible to views.

Comment: Is there a way to place the entire SKView over top of a UIImageView?

Comment: I believe it has been tried but so far I haven't seen anyone succeed. But in this particular case it seems awfully backwards, since you could simply put a sprite in the background with the contents intended for the UIImageView.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. You just saved me hours of headache.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImageView and its UIButton and whatever other content you want in there must be in a UIView that's sitting lower than the SKView you have the Sprite Kit contents in.

And you'll need to ensure the SKView is transparent (at least its background) and that it passes touches through to the UIView underneath if you need them down there sometimes.